# Evaluating the sum: $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{k^n}{(k!)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, bessel-functions

The sum:
$$S_2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{k^2}{(k!)^2}$$ is equal to:
$S_2=I_0(2)$ where $I_0(2)$ is the modifyed Bessel function of the first kind $I_0(x)$ calculated for $x=2$. $$S_3=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{k^3}{(k!)^2}$$
is equal to: $S_3=I_0(2)+I_1(2)$. For $n\gt3$ the result is a more complicated form involving Hypergeometric functions.
My question is: is it possible to find a closed formula for $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{k^n}{(k!)^2}?$$ Thanks in advance for any answer or hint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By using [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number) we have:
$$ k^n = \sum_{j=0}^{n}{n \brace j}(k)_j $$
where $(k)_j$ is the falling Pochhammer symbol: $(k)_j = k(k-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(k-j+1).$
Since:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(k)_j}{(k!)^2}=I_{-j}(2)$$
it follows that:

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{k^n}{(k!)^2}=\sum_{j=0}^{n}{n \brace j}I_{-j}(2)=\sum_{j=0}^{n}{n \brace j}I_{j}(2).$$

Have a look at [this](http://oeis.org/A086880) OEIS entry, too.

Comment: Interesting comparing this with Felix Marin's solution.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{S}_{n + 2} & = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{k^{n + 2} \over \pars{k!}^{2}} =
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{k^{n} \over \bracks{\pars{k - 1}!}^{2}} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{k + 1}^{n} \over \pars{k!}^{2}} = 
1 + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{k!}^{2}}
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{n}{n \choose \ell}k^{\ell}
\\[3mm] & = 
1 + \sum_{\ell = 0}^{n}{n \choose \ell}
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{k^{\ell} \over \pars{k}!^{2}}
\end{align}

---

\begin{equation}
\imp\quad S_{n + 2} =
1 + \sum_{\ell = 0}^{n}{n \choose \ell}S_{\ell}
\,;\qquad n \geq 0\,,\quad
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{S_{0}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\,\mathrm{I}_{0}\pars{2} - 1}
\\[1mm]
\ds{S_{1}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\,\mathrm{I}_{1}\pars{2}}
\end{array}\right.\tag{1}
\end{equation}

---

$$
\mbox{A few of them,}\quad
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcrcr}
\ds{S_{2}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\mathrm{I}_{0}\pars{2}}&&
\\[1mm]
\ds{S_{3}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\mathrm{I}_{0}\pars{2}} & \ds{+} & \ds{\mathrm{I}_{1}\pars{2}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{S_{4}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{2\,\mathrm{I}_{0}\pars{2}} & \ds{+} & \ds{2\,\mathrm{I}_{1}\pars{2}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{S_{5}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{5\,\mathrm{I}_{0}\pars{2}} & \ds{+} & \ds{4\,\mathrm{I}_{1}\pars{2}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{S_{6}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{13\,\mathrm{I}_{0}\pars{2}} & \ds{+} & \ds{10\,\mathrm{I}_{1}\pars{2}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{S_{7}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{36\,\mathrm{I}_{0}\pars{2}} & \ds{+} & \ds{29\,\mathrm{I}_{1}\pars{2}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{S_{8}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{109\,\mathrm{I}_{0}\pars{2}} & \ds{+} & \ds{90\,\mathrm{I}_{1}\pars{2}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{S_{9}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{359\,\mathrm{I}_{0}\pars{2}} & \ds{+} & \ds{295\,\mathrm{I}_{1}\pars{2}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{S_{10}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{1266\,\mathrm{I}_{0}\pars{2}} & \ds{+} & \ds{1030\,\mathrm{I}_{1}\pars{2}}
\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: If you defined $S_n$ as a sum starting with $k=0$ (under the convention $0^0=1$), then $S_0=I_0(2)$, which would make things a bit nicer.

Comment: @Batominovski Thanks for your remark. I was blindly following the OP definition. I'll check a little bit later your idea with my answer. Indeed, I was thinking I could find a generating function but it was not 'friendly enough'.

Comment: With this new convention, your answer will also agree with Jack D'Aurizio's answer when $n=0$.